# On the topology of the real hyperbolic space

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

I was looking at the real hyperbolic space $H^n$, defined as

$$H^n = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} | \left[ x, x \right] = 1, x_{n + 1} > 0 \right\rbrace,$$

where $\left[ x, y \right] = x_{n + 1}y_{n + 1} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} x_iy_i$.

We can define a distance function on $H^n$ as $d_H \left( x, y \right) = \cosh^{-1} \left( \left[ x, y \right] \right)$. This does turn out to be a distance function (metric). Now, at the same time, we can look at $H^n$ as the homogeneous space $SO_0 \left( n, 1 \right)/SO \left( n \right)$, where $SO_0 \left( n, 1 \right) = \left\lbrace A \in GL \left( n + 1, \mathbb{R} \right) | \left[ Ax, Ay \right] = \left[ x, y \right], \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}, \det A = 1, \langle Ae_{n + 1}, e_{n + 1} \rangle > 0 \right\rbrace$.

Thus, there are three different possible topologies on $H^n$:-

1. The subspace topology of $R^{n + 1}$,
2. The metric topology induced by $d_H$, and
3. The manifold topology of $SO_0 \left( n, 1 \right)/SO \left( n \right)$.

I was wondering if all of them are equal. Indeed, they should be since we do not make a difference between the metric topology and the manifold topology (as far as I know). However, I am not able to prove it! My initial idea was to show that the metric topology of $d_H$ is the same as subspace topology and that $SO_0 \left( n, 1 \right)/SO \left( n \right)$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$. However, neither seems to come naturally.

Any insights into this will be appreciable! Thanks in advance!

PS: I do not want to use the fact that $d_H$ comes from a Riemannian metric.

Comment: Your definition of $H^n$ is not quite right. As for your question of comparing the topologies, start by observing continuity of the function $d(x,y)$ on $H^n\times H^n$ with respect to the subspace topology. Could you verify at least this? By the way, did you already verify that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, I have checked that $d_H$ does satisfy the triangle inequality. As for the definition of $H^n$, I had missed a condition, which I have added now. Also, I will check the continuity of $d_H$ with respect to the subspace topology. t first glance it seems very easy to prove. Since if we take any sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in subspace topology, then all its coordinates converge and continuity follows from the algebra of convergent sequences and continuity of $\cosh^{-1}$. How does this help further, though?

Comment: Think how continuity implies that the metric topology is weaker than the standard topology. Incidentally, there is no need to work with sequences, you should be able to use limit theorems that you learned in your calculus (or real analysis, or general topology) classes, such as continuity of the composition of continuous functions, as well as the sum rule and the product rule for limits of functions of several variables.